# Search function is work but insert function isn't work in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am self-learn php language. I create the PHP code for the insert to data and search data in databases. I want to insert & search data to the database with MySQL and PHP. I used WAMP server. Finally, the search function is working correctly, but insert function is didn't work.

**table**

[image]

my error in

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message '

PHP code is:

```
if(isset($_POST['insert'])){
  $data = getPosts();
  $sql = "INSERT INTO users (id, fname, lname, age) VALUES ('$data[0]','$data[1],'$data[2]','$data[3]')";

  $result= mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
if($result){
    echo 'Insert is success.....'; 
}
else{
    echo 'Insert is unsuccess';
}
}

function getPosts(){

    $posts = array();
    $posts[0] = $_POST['id'];
    $posts[1] = $_POST['fname'];
    $posts[2] = $_POST['lname'];
    $posts[3] = $_POST['age'];
    return $posts;
}

//Search
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $data = getPosts();
    $search_Query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $data[0]";
    $search_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $search_Query);
    if($search_Result)
    {
        if(mysqli_num_rows($search_Result))
        {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_Result))
            {
                $id = $row['id'];
                $fname = $row['fname'];
                $lname = $row['lname'];
                $age = $row['age'];
            }
        }
        else{
            echo 'No Data for this id';
        }
    }else{
        echo 'Result Error';
    }
}
```

html code:

```
 <form action="" method="post">
  Enter Your Id: <input type="number" name="id" placeholder="Id" value="<?php echo $id;?>"><br><br>
  Enter Your First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" value="<?php echo $fname;?>"><br><br>
  Enter Your Last Name:<input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" value="<?php echo $lname;?>"><br><br>
  Enter Your Age:<input type="number" name="age" placeholder="Age" value="<?php echo $age;?>"><br><br>
  <div>
   <input type = "submit" name="insert" value="Add">
   <input type = "submit" name="search" value="Search">
  </div>
  </form>
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks any audience.

Comment: Isn't id autoincrement column?

Comment: Please share the table structure of your `users` table.

Comment: Try to use prepared statement to avoid sql injection .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (id, fname, lname, age) VALUES ('$data[0]','$data[1],'$data[2]','$data[3]')";
```

Replace the above line with

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (id, fname, lname, age) VALUES ('{$data[0]}','{$data[1]}','{$data[2]}','{$data[3]}')";
```

or

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (id, fname, lname, age) VALUES ('".$data[0]."','".$data[1]."','".$data[2]."','".$data[3]."')";
```

Answer (score 4):

You forgot single quote(`'`) after `$data[1]` in your insert query.

Change your insert query with this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (id, fname, lname, age) VALUES ('".$data[0]."','".$data[1]."','".$data[2]."','".$data[3]."')";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO users (id, fname, lname, age) VALUES ('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]')";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (id, fname, lname, age) VALUES ('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]')";
```

You omitted one ' in your query after `'$data[1],` which is suppose  to be `'$data[1]'`

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO users (id, fname, lname, age) VALUES ('$data[0]','$data[1],'$data[2]','$data[3]')";
```